# How to mount a CDROM on a Xen guest virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, xen, mount, optical-media

How to mount a CDROM on a Xen guest virtual machine? I tried adding this to the *disk array* with no success

```
'phy:/dev/cdrom,xvdb:cdrom,r'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under xen 3.0.2 I did successfully this:

```
xm block-attach etch2 file://etc/xen/grml_1.1.iso /dev/sdd r
```

In domU I could see the device with `fdisk -l` and mount /dev/sdd as usual.

Perhaps you should try this:

```
'phy:/dev/cdrom,xvdb:/dev/cdrom,r'
```